# can not load assembly

Tags: json, dll, json.net, coolite

I am working on C#, 2012 visual studio project. when I copy my project to another computer and try to run it, it throws the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The system can not find the file. calling assembly: Coolite.Ext.Web .dll

I downloaded Newtonsoft.Json, Version=3.5.0.0 and referenced it in the project still the same error. I have also tried to redirect it using runtime redirection in the web.config, still no hope.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you target the proper framework in VS.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202(v=vs.110).aspx

Also make sure you're getting it from NuGet to ensure you have the most up to date version

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/